# How to get notified when the user clicks the header column check box in VirtualTreeView control?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

Is there an event notifying about the VirtualTreeView header column check box click? It is the check box highlighted on this picture:

[image]

Comment: In `OnColumnsHeaderClick` you can test `if (hhiOnCheckbox in HitInfo.HitPosition) then`.

Comment: @TLama You mean 'OnHeaderClick' I think. And it works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: D'oh. Sure, it's `OnHeaderClick`. I've copied a part of a method name from a real application (where VT was related to export columns, hence that extra `Columns` in the name).

Comment: And now, how can I get the state of this header checkbox? I tried a lot and could not find a way to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a handler for the `OnHeaderClick` event and check if the `HitPosition` property of the `HitInfo` parameter contains the `hhiOnCheckbox` flag. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualTreeHeaderClick(Sender: TVTHeader; HitInfo: TVTHeaderHitInfo);
begin
  if hhiOnCheckbox in HitInfo.HitPosition then
  begin
    if Sender.Columns[HitInfo.Column].CheckState = csCheckedNormal then
      ShowMessage('Checked!')
    else
      ShowMessage('Unchecked!')
  end;
end;
```